# dockerfile cmd run multiple command

Tags: docker, cmd

I have combine shellinabox and redis in a docker image。

my Dockerfile is simply as below：

```
CMD ['/usr/local/work/scripts/run.sh']

ENTRYPOINT  ["bin/bash"]

EXPOSE 4200/tcp
```

the `run.sh` is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $REDIS_HOME
src/redis-server
/usr/bin/shellinaboxd -p 4200
```

I want start the redis server and shellinabox both when docker start.
by only the redis is start.

when I start the docker and use ctrl +c the shellinabox begin start.

I know how to use 'supervisor' figure out this.
Anyone know how to use shell script both start this two services?

Comment: You can try `redis-server --daemonize yes`. This should launch redis-server in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In docker philosophy, you should have one process per container, and you could use docker-compose to start two containers one for redis, one for shellinaboxd.

But sometimes it's easier or for some other reasons :

In your script shell "src/redis-server" launch redis and stay attached to console, until it's stopped (with ctrl+c by e.g.) and then launch shellinaboxd.

You can try by replace this line "src/redis-server" with "nohup src/redis-server &", then redis will be launch in fork process, and will let shellinaboxd start.

Solution with docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    build: ./Dockerfile
    command: /usr/bin/src/redis-server
  shellinabox:
    build: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    command: /usr/bin/shellinaboxd -p 4200
```

Answer (score 2):

You must never start a service in the background in an entrypoint.sh! The docker-stop command will send a SIGINT only to the PID 1 of a container to allow it shutdown cleanly, ten seconds later it will be a SIGKILL to the remaining processes. Unless entrypoint.sh has some "trap" parts one can easily trash the contained data.

I have learned about those details while working on https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement so that it can run as a init-replacement as well. In that mode you just say CMD /usr/bin/systemctl.py and every systemD service that was enabled will have their ExecStart sequences be run. Upon a docker-stop it will get their ExecStop be run for a clean shutdown.

That's the way that I run multiple services in one container.